# ReferenceError: Template is not defined in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

As far as I can see all the javascript files and html are correct.

```
W20151006-00:40:17.144(0)? (STDERR)
W20151006-00:40:17.145(0)? (STDERR) /home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.b2s4xu++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib
/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151006-00:40:17.147(0)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20151006-00:40:17.149(0)? (STDERR)                                                   ^
W20151006-00:40:17.158(0)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Template is not defined
W20151006-00:40:17.158(0)? (STDERR)     at Client/Controllers/convert.js:1:1
W20151006-00:40:17.159(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/nitrous/Assignment_1a/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/Client/Controllers/convert.js:33:4
W20151006-00:40:17.159(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/nitrous/Assignment_1a/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20151006-00:40:17.159(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20151006-00:40:17.159(0)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.b2s4xu++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.
linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20151006-00:40:17.159(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/nitrous/Assignment_1a/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20151006-00:40:21.743(0)? (STDERR)
W20151006-00:40:21.744(0)? (STDERR) /home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.b2s4xu++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib
/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151006-00:40:21.745(0)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20151006-00:40:21.747(0)? (STDERR)                                                   ^
W20151006-00:40:21.757(0)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Template is not defined
W20151006-00:40:21.757(0)? (STDERR)     at Client/Controllers/convert.js:1:1
W20151006-00:40:21.757(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/nitrous/Assignment_1a/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/Client/Controllers/convert.js:33:4
W20151006-00:40:21.757(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/nitrous/Assignment_1a/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20151006-00:40:21.757(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20151006-00:40:21.757(0)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/nitrous/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.b2s4xu++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.
linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20151006-00:40:21.758(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/nitrous/Assignment_1a/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

I am using

```
autopublish           1.0.4 
blaze-html-templates  1.0.1 
ecmascript            0.1.5 
es5-shim              4.1.13  
insecure              1.0.4  
jquery                1.11.4  
meteor-base           1.0.1  
mobile-experience     1.0.1  
mongo                 1.1.2  
session               1.1.1  
standard-minifiers    1.0.1 
tracker               1.0.9  
twbs:bootstrap        3.3.5
```

It is failing on one template, I have three.

Any help to find what the issue might be would be great.

**EDIT:**
I have them all three are in a sub-folder, all of the js is in Client/ Controllers.

[File system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh5PT.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor's directory structure is case sensitive. Use `client` instead of `Client` to solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry but as I have three templates and they are all separated in the Client folder together then I don't think that solves the issue.

Thanks any way for the reply

Comment: You still need to make client lowercase regardless.

Comment: Thanks that was it, and actually makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Your client code is apparently running on the server where `Template` is not defined (along with many other objects, ex: jQuery). Template helpers are client-side only.

Comment: I have added the filing system image into my question.

The templates are all located in the client folder not the server folder, so does that mean they are located in the client not server?

Comment: Are they in `Client` or `client`?

Comment: The issue was that Client folder and it should be client folder, thanks. Already solved by another helper :)

Comment: This answer helped me; thanks. I was getting this error simply because I was following a newbie Meteor guide and it wasn't clear that `Template...` was supposed to go inside `if (Meteor.isClient)...`