# Meteor can't find my template when I call it from javascript - for no reason?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using meteor & bootstrap for a very basic application. I've set up some dummy code that accurately replicates what I'm trying to do:

In the HTML:

```
 <template name='test'>
  <p> Im a test </p>
</template>
```

In the JS:

```
Template.test.helpers({
})
```

I'm getting a

```
ReferenceError: Template is not defined
```

On the line that I call the test template. Why could this be? I have defined the template and now cannot handle - well, anything at all.

Thank you for reading

Comment: check the paths the files are included in? `client`/`server`

Comment: Thanks for your help David. The issue came from the fact that meteors file structure is case-sensitive. This link helped a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960042/referenceerror-template-is-not-defined-in-meteor